# Search elements of an array within elements of a different array to extract exact or similar keys and their values in PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of keywords which I can separate them through the following code and insert them in separate rows in database:

```
$comma  = "";
$values = "";
$array  = explode(",", mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $post['keywords']));
foreach ($array as $key_value) {
    $key_value = str_replace(" ", '', $key_value);
    $values .= $comma."('$id', '$activation', '$key_value')";
    $comma = ",";
}
$insert = mysqli_query($db_connect, "INSERT INTO database.keywords
            (id, activation, keywords) VALUES $values");
```

An example of `$post['keywords']` is in below:

```
Array ( [keywords] => Database, Law, Tech, Creative )
```

As you can see in the above example, `$key_value` values are `Database`, `Law`, `Tech` and `Creative`.

My problem is that I want to search each element of the above example in a different array called `$list` to extract keys and their values with exact or similar words in `$post['keywords']`. For example, assume that below is our `$list` array:

```
$list = array(
    "Data" => "9",
    "Data Structure" => "10",
    "Database" => "11",
    "Creativity" => "12",
    "Forest" => "13",
    "Al Pacino" => "14",
    "Humans" => "15",
    "Technology" => "16"
);
```

So, `Database` in `$post['keywords']` meets three keys in the above example as `"Data"`, `"Data Structure"` and `"Database"` in `$list`.

`Law` in `$post['keywords']` meets no key in `$list`.

`Tech` in `$post['keywords']` meets `Technology` as its key in `$list`.

And finally `Creative` in `$post['keywords']` meets `Creativity` as its key in `$list`.

Hence my ultimate goal is to generate a new string variable like `$all_key_values="9,10,11,12,16"` as well as the new string variable like:

```
$all_keys="Data,Data Structure,Database,Creativity,Technology"
```

Comment: How would `Database` match `Data` and `Data Structure`? How exactly are you wanting the computer to determine "similar words"?

Comment: @Abraham, thanks Abraham for your time.. in this case since `Data` characters are in `Database`, it can be one of my keywords; however, I don't really know how to define the similarity. Something 80-90% of similar letters would be good.

Comment: tested `similar_text()` it just got to 45% or > based on the words that was needed to get a good hit

Comment: @kevinabelita, Kevin, could you please submit your answer?

Comment: @Apiah you could give a go with Marks answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are tricky. I thought I'd take a crack at it. This may not entirely solve your problem, but maybe it will get you on the right track.

My first thought was to use [**similar_text()**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.similar-text.php), which will count the number of matching characters in a string and return the number, or the percentage. This by itself, though, doesn't really work - matching "data" and "database" returns only a 50% similarity. So, I added in an additional check using [**stripos**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

Here is what I was playing with. Not perfect, but perhaps it will help:

```
$list = array(
    "Data" => "9",
    "Data Structure" => "10",
    "Database" => "11",
    "Creativity" => "12",
    "Forest" => "13",
    "Al Pacino" => "14",
    "Humans" => "15",
    "Technology" => "16"
    );

$post = array ('Database', 'Law', 'Tech', 'Creative');

$all_key_values = $all_keys = array();

foreach ($post as $keyword) {
    foreach ($list as $word=>$num) {
        $sim_chars = similar_text($keyword, $word);
        if ($sim_chars/strlen($keyword) > .8 || $sim_chars/strlen($word) > .8) {
            $all_key_values[] = $num;
            $all_keys[] = $word;
        }
        elseif (stripos($keyword, $word) !== false || strpos($word, $keyword) !== false) {
            $sll_key_values[] = $num;
            $all_keys[] = $word;
        }
    }        
}

print_r(implode(',', $all_key_values));
print_r(implode(',', $all_keys));
```

Output:

```
9,11,16,12
Data,Database,Technology,Creativity
```

As you can see, it doesn't match "data structure" and "database", because the 4 matching characters is not 80% of either word.

[**Here's a demo to play with**](http://3v4l.org/JlKFQ)

Comment: thanks a lot Mark for taking time and helping on this problem, cheers,

Comment: @Apiah Play around with `similar_text()`. It's pretty new to me and there may be a better way to use it, particularly the third percentage parameter. I have noticed that order of the first two arguments changes the outcome... anyways, happy coding, cheers

Comment: @Apiah LOL I just can't stop thinking about this one... you might also look into [**fnmatch()**](http://us2.php.net/fnmatch) ... a wildcard string matching function. Could be helpful.